# Select FindBugs plugins via command line

Tags: java, findbugs

Is it possible to configure which plugins FindBugs will load when invoking it from the command line? By default, it appears to load everything in the plugins directory and I didn't see any command line options relating to plugins in the manual.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`-choosePlugins` option](https://github.com/findbugsproject/findbugs/blob/f0386941/findbugs/src/java/edu/umd/cs/findbugs/TextUICommandLine.java#L202) to enable/disable plugins selectively, or `-pluginList` to specify which .jar file you want to load.

Or you may use following options to enable/disable detectors (visitors) in plugin:

- `-visitors` option, to enable only specific detectors
- `-omitVisitors` option, to disable only specific detectors
- `-chooseVisitors` option, to toggle specific detectors

reference: `java -jar findbugs.jar -textui -help` will print all options, including above options.

Comment: I am using `-pluginList` successfully but can't find any documentation about it anywhere?  Any idea why?  I would like to load multiple plugin jars but haven't figured out how yet.

Comment: BTW it's better to use SpotBugs instead. https://mailman.cs.umd.edu/pipermail/findbugs-discuss/2017-September/004383.html